# Сочетание причастного оборота и определения-прилагательного

Tags: пунктуация, определения, причастный-оборот, однородные-члены

Есть три схожих случая:

1. ...я проникаюсь уважением/почтением как к убеленным сединами, общепризнанным руководителям-профессорам...
2. ...Другое дело подвести под ротацию убеленных сединами почтенных профессоров...
3. ...отдельные руководители нашего вуза посматривали на нас – убеленных сединами, авторитетных в науке профессоров...

Мне кажется, что здесь все три случая - это сочетание идущего впереди причастного оборота и определения-прилагательного, описанное здесь [Знаки препинания при однородных определениях | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

И поэтому, по моему мнению, или вернее, пытаясь вывести вывод из этого правила, запятых не нужно во всех трех случаях... Но и в первом, и особенно в третьем случае я сомневаюсь... Может, здесь нужно рассматривать эти определения по каким-то другим критериям?..

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы! Значит, интуитивно я была права... Всегда нужно доверять интуиции, если не знаешь... )))

Answer (score 3):

***Убеленный сединами*** –  словосочетание с двойным значением: а) мудрый, авторитетный, общепризнанный; б) старый, почтенного возраста.

В предложении 2:  убеленные сединами почтенные (пожилые) профессора. Определения **неоднородные,** прямое значение сочетания *убеленные сединами.*

В предложениях 1 и 3: убеленные сединами, общепризнанные, авторитетные профессора. Это **однородные** определения, раскрывают одну тему. Переносное значение сочетания *убеленные сединами".

В предложении 3 - два определительных оборота, запятая ставится обязательно.

Answer (score 2):

Да, первые два случая - это сочетание идущего впереди причастного оборота и определения-прилагательного. Запятая не ставится если это **однородные** определения. Осталось понять, являются ли опредeления однородными во всех трех приведенных случаях.

В первом случае каждое из определений относится непосредственно к определяемому слову, определения характеризуют руководителей-профессорoв с разных сторон: они убелены сединами **и** общепризнаны. Вывод: определения однородны, запятая нужна.

Во втором случае первое определение (убеленных сединами) относится к последующему словосочетанию (почтенных профессоров). Вывод: определения неоднородны, запятая не нужна.

В третьем случае, по-моему, можно увидеть как однородные, так и неоднородные 
(если все герои были действительно убелены сединами) определения. Но вопрос решается в пользу постановки запятой, потому что оба определения распространены.

Comment: @ М_Г, если определения неоднородны, то запятая не нужна, и, наоборот, если однородны, запятая нужна. У вас в ответе наоборот.

Comment: @Серж, Спасибо, исправил.